# Book Recommendation: Series and Sequences of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence, book-recommendation, sequence-of-function

I would like recommendations on calculus books that explain series and sequences of **functions** that clearly cover:

- pointwise convergence
- uniformly convergence
- uniformly convergence in compact sets
- normal convergence for series of functions
- the implications of those convergences (e.g. the limit of the integral of a sequence/series of functions is the integral of its limit, and the same for derivatives)
- Abel's criterion
- power series of functions

For reference, I am a second year undergrad maths student

Comment: As a side lecture you can read https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Gallery-Masterpieces-Newton-Lebesgue/dp/0691136262. This is not a "school" book, but about history. However, this book is wonderful to see where come from all these ideas and IMHO it really provides the "big picture" of all this.

Comment: @PicaudVincent thank you very much, it sounds quite interesting! I'll be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your reference to "normal convergence" I suspect you're learning mathematics in French.

You ought to find most of what you need in Chapters 1 to 3 of Volume 4 of *Cours de mathématiques spéciales* by Ramis.

Comment: You got me! Touché ! Thank you very much, it seems to have what I'm looking for.